# How a save figure as an eps file with Chinese characters inside in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using Windows XP (simplified Chinese version), matlab 2011b.

I can draw my figure successfully using matlab with Chinese chars in labels, legends, titles, etc. And it can be saved to bitmap files just well. But When I save the figure into eps file, the character become garbled.

I know I can edit the saved eps file to get it right,but is there a way to successfully save such figures as eps? A Linux solution is also OK for me.

Comment: I've still not found a solution. However, as I was just planning to include it into a latex file, I found matlab2tikz which can be used. I can even get a pdf then eps through the latex file, but I don't think it is an answer to the question.